# How to assign values to dataframe column from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

I have a **dataframe** like this

```
   c1 
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   b
```

and
a dictionary like this:

```
di = {
'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40
}
```

I want column `c2` in my DataFrame like this

```
   c1  c2
0   a  10
1   b  20
2   c  30
3   d  40
4   b  20
```

**Here is the code to generate your df and di:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b']})
di = {
'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) module of a `pandas.Series` object

```
df['c2'] = df['c1'].map(di)
```

Output

```
#   c1  c2
# 0  a  10
# 1  b  20
# 2  c  30
# 3  d  40
# 4  b  20
```